# Getter returning 0 [Java]

Tags: java, actionlistener, getter

I'm trying to call a Getter from another class, and when I do, it returns and prints 0 every time. **It generates a random number when you click the easyButton. After I click that button, it still shows zero after I call the getter with the enterInputButton**. 
Here is the code. 
I have print statements to show that it doesn't work. I do this in other classes, and it works in my other small projects.
I just dont understand why it returns 0 after I call it in the print statement, when I click the enterInputButton.
Thank you so much!
(Its my first time posting here)

```
public class UserInputPanel extends JPanel
{
    private DifficultyPanel grabDiff;
    private SpringLayout baseLayout;

    private JTextField userGuessField;
    private JButton enterInputButton;

    private int userGuess;

    //Class that needs the random Number
    public UserInputPanel() 
    {
        grabDiff = new DifficultyPanel();

        baseLayout = new SpringLayout();

        userGuessField = new JTextField(2);
        enterInputButton = new JButton("Enter Guess");

        buildPanel();
        buildWindow();
        buildListeners();
    }

    private void buildPanel()
    {
        setBackground(Color.RED);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
        setLayout(baseLayout);
        add(userGuessField);
        add(enterInputButton);
    }

    private void buildWindow()
    {

    }

    private void buildListeners()
    {
        enterInputButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent clicked)
                {
                    parseInput();
                    System.out.println("MY INPUT " + userGuess);

                    //This line prints it to 0
                    System.out.println("GEN NUM : " + grabDiff.getSelectedNumber());
                }
            });
    }

    private void parseInput()
    {
        userGuess = Integer.parseInt(userGuessField.getText());
    }
}
```

And here is the class that has the variable.

```
public class DifficultyPanel extends JPanel
{
    private SpringLayout baseLayout;

    private JButton easyButton;

    private int selectedNumber;

    public DifficultyPanel()
    {
        baseLayout = new SpringLayout();

        easyButton = new JButton("Easy");

        buildPanel();
        buildListeners();
    }

    private void buildPanel()
    {
        setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));

        setLayout(baseLayout);
        add(easyButton);
    }

    private void buildListeners()
    {
        easyButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent click)
                {
                    selectedNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 51);
                    System.out.println(selectedNumber);
                }
            });
    }


    public int getSelectedNumber()
    {
        System.out.println(selectedNumber);
        return this.selectedNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: Since "it" works in other projects - what did you do differently? When is the number changed, i.e. the `easyButton` being clicked?

Comment: I dont see you have set it anywhere. You made grabDiff as a new object and just call that get select number

Comment: `selectedNumber` is being set in the `ActionListener` on `easyButton`. As long as the methods are called and the button is pressed in the correct order, the `selectedNumber` field ought to be set to something.

Comment: Sorry! Added the bold part at the top. Might clear up some confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an instance of `DifficultyPanel` called `grabDiff` in `UserInputPanel` as a private field, and trying to get the number from that. But you never add that `grabDiff` to the `UserInputPanel` or any other container, so the user can never click the button in it. I suspect you have another instance of `DifficultyPanel` somewhere else (in some code you didn't post), and that is the one that has the number set in it.

[Edit]

If you wanted to add `grabDiff` to your `DifficultyPanel`, you could put an `add` line into `DifficultyPanel.buildPanel`, something like this:

```
private void buildPanel()
{
    setBackground(Color.RED);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
    setLayout(baseLayout);
    add(grabDiff); // <- new line
    add(userGuessField);
    add(enterInputButton);
}
```

Comment: How do you add grabDiff to the UserInputPanel then? Here is my Github with the classes. https://github.com/Wh3at1y/GuessingGAMEAGAIN/tree/master/src/game